# How do I update a filter return value in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

My filter depends on service `service.show()` return value:

```
angular.module('util')
    .filter('formatMoney', ['accounting', 'service', function (accounting, service) {
        return function (number) {
            return service.show()
                ? accounting.formatMoney(number, '€', 3, '.', '.', '%s %v')
                : '';
        };
    }]);
```

At runtime `service.show()` can change, returning `true` or `false`. But the returning value of the filter doesn't change.

How can I force an update of all `formatMoney` filters, without using `$scope` or controllers?

Answer (score 2):

You can try the stateful filters, described [here](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.7/docs/guide/filter). This means you will only need to add the `$stateful` annotation to your filter as:

```
angular.module('util')
    .filter('formatMoney', ['accounting', 'service', function (accounting, service) {
        function formatMoney(number) {
            return service.show()
                ? accounting.formatMoney(number, '€', 3, '.', '.', '%s %v')
                : '';
        }
        formatMoney.$stateful = true;
        return formatMoney;
    }]);
```

Note also the warning from Angular docs:

> It is strongly discouraged to write filters that are stateful, because the execution of those can't be optimized by Angular, which often leads to performance issues. Many stateful filters can be converted into stateless filters just by exposing the hidden state as a model and turning it into an argument for the filter.

Comment: Nevermind, it works out of the box without the stateful flag (bonus question: why?). Don't know why it didn't work the first time, i'll update my question asap. Thanks.